# What in the constitution gives a right to carry concealed?

Tags: constitutional-law

I understand the legal framework of right-to-carry as framed in the 2nd amendment.  What grants the right to carry concealed?  Why can't laws be made which make people carry their weapon in a visible location?

Answer (score 2):

Numerous states require a permit to carry a concealed weapon, and no state categorically forbid carrying of concealed weapons. Historically (19th century), concealed carry was forbidden in some states, and was upheld e.g. in [North Carolina v. Kerner](https://guncite.com/court/state/107se222.html), 181 N.C. 574. However, the right to carry a concealed weapon flows from the 2nd Amendment. If it is legal to carry a weapon, it is legal to carry a concealed weapon unless a legislature (or constitution) expressly forbids it. In North Carolina a law was passed which forbade carrying concealed firearms (as was expressly allows by the state Constitution), and this law was upheld.

A state could pass a law generally forbidding concealed carry (as has been done); or requiring a permit to carry a concealed weapon (as is the case in some states).

Comment: "the right to carry a concealed weapon" would seem to imply that a state cannot forbid it.  Therefore, if "it is legal to carry a concealed weapon unless the legislature forbids it" then there is no right to carry a concealed weapon, much less one flowing from the second amendment.